# Having difficulty writing jasmine unit tests for Angular where there are a lot of dependencies

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to AngularJS. We are using the karma/jasmine testing tool.

I am going to past the code I am trying to unit test here. I hope you can help me write a unit test. I am able to write very simple unit tests. But modules where there are a lot dependencies are giving me trouble.

Here is the code I am trying to unit test:

```
var referencedataservice = angular.module('referenceDataService', []);

referencedataservice.factory('dataService', function($localStorage, $http, constant) {
    var username = $localStorage.user.username;
    var password = $localStorage.user.password;

    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
    };

    function getCountries() {
        request.url = constant.URL_GET_COUNTRIES;
        return $http(request).then(
            function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
     }
}
```

Here is the what the constants service looks like:

```
angular.module('constantsService', []).constant("constant", {
    "URL_GET_COUNTRIES": "app/lookup/getCountries",
    "URL_GET_PRODUCT_TYPES": "app/lookup/getProductTypes",
});
```

I can unit test the constantsService quite easily. But I am unable to figure out how to write the unit test for my referenceDataService. Here is my attempt at it:

```
describe("Test Reference Data Service", function() {
  var a;
  var dataService;
  var $localStorage;
  var constant;
  var $http;

  beforeEach(module('ngStorage', 'constantsService', 'referenceDataService'));


  beforeEach(inject(function($localStorage, _constant_, _dataService_) {
    constant = _constant_;
    $http = _$http_;
    dataService = _dataService_;
  }));


  it("should be the same", function() {
    var countries;

    dataService.getCountries().then(function(data) {
        countries = data.referenceDataValues;
    });
    a = countries[0].id;
    expect(a).toBe("1000000");
  });
});
```

It obviously doesn't work. The tests don't even compile. Keep getting dependancy related errors. I just don't know how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your getCountries is async so you need to use the "done" in your test.

```
 it("should be the same", function(done) {
    var countries;

    dataService.getCountries().then(function(data) {
        countries = data.referenceDataValues;
        a = countries[0].id;
        expect(a).toBe("1000000");
        done();
    });
  });
```

Source: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html